# ASP.NET Core MVC - editing a list of entities

Tags: c#, data-binding, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to dip my toe into frontend development with ASP.NET Core 5 MVC - but I'm not really having much success so far... I'm more of a backend developer - give me a SQL Server database, and a ASP.NET Core Web API, and I'm happy - but this frontend wizardry is not quite my strong suit ...

OK, so I'm trying something *extremely* simple - a Razor page to edit a list of something, add a numerical value to each of those somethings, and then storing them.

I have a model/DTO class like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, in reality, it has many more properties - but those aren't relevant here. What is: name and city are given, and I need to add the `CustomerId` to it (in our case, the `CustomerId` is handled by SAP - so we need to manually add those after the customer has been created there).

I have a really simple Razor page which basically shows the list of customers, allows me to enter the `CustomerId` in the last column, and then I have a `POST` method on the same Razor page that gets hit when the user clicks on the `Update` (submit) button.

Here's my view:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<h3 class="display-4">Customers</h3>

@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Model.Message))
{
    <div class="container">
        <span class="@Model.MessageClass mt-4 mb-5">@Model.Message</span>
    </div>
}

<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col-md-2">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col-md-2">City</th>
                    <th scope="col-md-1">CustomerId</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Customers.Count; index++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Model.Customers[index].Name</td>
                        <td>@Model.Customers[index].City</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" asp-for="Customers[index].CustomerId" id="Customers[@index]" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and this is my "code-behind" for this Razor page:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string MessageClass { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Customers = CustomerProvider.GetCustomers();
    }

    public async Task OnPostAsync()
    {
        Customers = CustomerProvider.GetCustomers();

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(Customers))
        {
            Message = "Customers successfully updated";
            MessageClass = "alert-success";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "Customer update did not work";
            MessageClass = "alert-danger";
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing too fancy here - I basically get a list of customers from somewhere (a database, in reality), I display that list, I can enter customer id values into the grid, and I was expecting to get back the updated `Customers` in my `OnPostAsync` method.

Now the code runs fine, shows the list of customers, I can enter values into the `CustomerId` column, and I can click on "Update". The `OnPostAsync` method gets called, I fetch the customers again, and I was expecting the `await TryUpdateModelAsync` to update my customers with the `CustomerId` values that I have entered.

**But it does not do that** - after my `GetCustomers` call, I have my four test customers - as expected - but after the `TryUpdateModelAsync`, that list is empty... The call to  `TryUpdateModelAsync` works - it returns `true` - but the list of customers isn't updated with the information entered on screen - quite the contrary, the list is wiped out ...

I also tried to use

```
public async Task OnPostAsync([FromForm] List<Customer> updatedCustomers)
```

hoping that the MVC data binding would return back the list of updated customers - but this `updatedCustomers` is `null` and doesn't send back the entered data...

But when I look at `HttpContext.Request.Form` - I **do see** the values that were entered:

[image]

but somehow, those aren't handled properly and not applied to the `Customers` list...

Any ideas? I must be missing something really silly somewhere - but I just cannot find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the values in two ways:

### 1. Using `[BindProperty]`

Add a property to your model and annotate it with `[BindProperty]`. When you build inputs with `asp-for="@Model.MyList[i].AProp"` it will be bound to form values when submitted.

**Note:** You still need to render read-only properties in HTML with hidden inputs (`<input type="hidden" />`) for those values to be available when the form is submitted, otherwise you'll get sentinel/null values.

Assuming you have a Razor template as follows:

```
<form method="POST">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Customers.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" 
                           readonly 
                           value="@Model.Customers[i].CustomerId" 
                           asp-for="@Model.Customers[i].CustomerId"/> <!-- asp-for attributes are indexed for each item -->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" 
                           value="@Model.Customers[i].Name"
                           asp-for="@Model.Customers[i].Name"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

you need a model with a bound property:

```cs
public record Customer(string CustomerId, string Name);
public class HomeModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

When rendered, you should have inputs with indexed `name` attributes:

```html
<input type="text" value="Bob" id="Customers_1__Name" name="Customers[1].Name"/>
```

When you submit the form, `Model.Customers` will be populated with the values.

### 2. Using `[FromForm]` attribute

You can also accept a parameter **of the same name as input names**. This means if the input names are like `Customers[1].Name`, the parameter name must be `customers` (case insensitive) (not `updatedCustomers` like you have). Or you can **specify a different name** using `[FromForm(Name = "customers")] updatedCustomers`.

```cs
// this works
public ActionResult OnPost([FromForm]List<Customer> customers)
{
    return Page();
}

// this also works
public ActionResult OnPost([FromForm(Name = "customers")]List<Customer> updatedCustomers)
{
    return Page();
}
```

If the model has a bound property (`[BindProperty]`), it will also be populated with the form values in addition to the parameter.

### Further info

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-input-tag-helper

Comment: Thanks - works - partly. The `[BindProperty]` is OK - I get the values in the Post method - but *only* if I make them editable - and I don't want to do this for the Name and City of the customers. I tried with `<label asp-for="...">` - but that didn't work - in the Post method, those values are gone again ;-( The approach with the `[FromForm]` with the *correct name* for the parameter also works - thanks!

Comment: `<label asp-for="...">` did you mean `<input asp-for`?

Comment: No - I mean `<label asp-for` - because I want the "City" and "Name" to be read-only and **not** editable - `<input>` implies editable fields - doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, ok. Keep in mind that **only inputs with `name` attributes (that are not disabled)** are submitted. You can't use `label`s to send values back. Those must be sent as (hidden) inputs with `name`s.

Answer (score 1):

Ah if I understand this case right then you are missing a very little part.

So you want to send a list/array type parameter to your POST method, but your POST method does not know about the object which is coming as a parameter. So you should define as a `name` attribute onto your input.

```
<input type="number" name="customerIds" asp-for="Customers[index].CustomerId" id="Customers[@index]" />
```

and your POST method should meet the parameter as an `int[]` type.

```
public async Task OnPostAsync(int[] customerIds)
{
      //Now you have edited customerIds as an integer array type and you can manuplate it.
}
```

Comment: Yes - OK - I get the list of the values I've entered - but how do I know to which customer each of those values belongs now??

Comment: Ah my bad, I thought you only needed customerIds, so I have also up-voted the above answer.